# Which key-value database should I use?

Tags: nosql, redis, hbase, berkeley-db, in-memory-database

My application will use hundered's of tables and each table can have millions(4-5) of Key-Value pairs. No relations are required between tables.

Following are the operations I perform on the tables.

1. Which use's a perfect blend of In-Memory caching and Persistent storage, Failure tolerant and able to recover from failures.
2. Update value for a particular key very frequently. A single thread does it for a particular key.
3. Need sorted order of keys in a table based on value.(Frequently used)
4. A few key-value pair inserts.

There are quite a few No Sql databases like Apache H-Base, Cassandra, Berkeley DB, Redis..etc Pls suggest me which works best for my use case. What are the system requirements ?

Comment: @RahulAttuluri What language is your application written in?

Comment: Application is written in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which use's a perfect blend of In-Memory caching and Persistent
>   storage, Failure tolerant and able to recover from failures.

Redis is currently probably the most popular (not only) K/V in-memory data store solution. To make it fault tolerant you can leverage it's master-slave [replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication) feature.

> Update value for a particular key very frequently. A single thread
>   does it for a particular key.

Not sure what you mean by "a single thread does it for a particular key", but redis is [designed to be very fast](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks).

> Need sorted order of keys in a table based on value.(Frequently used)

Redis supports [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) data structure.

> What are the system requirements?

As of amount of memory requirement I would recommend to read the [doc on memory optimization](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization).

Answer (score 0):

suggesting Redis
p3. needs some redundancy of storage to solve keys in sorted set.
but, still here one question: did you have so many memory?